# Which regex use to keep all before last "\" character

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a string like this:

```
$logFile = "\\MyServer\Shared\Folder1\test.log"
```

With PowerShell i would like to parse this string to have:

```
$logFileTree = "\\MyServer\Shared\Folder1\"
```

I tried this:

```
$logFileTree = $logFile -replace '^.*\\'
```

but the result is not good (`$logFileTree = test.log`)

Comment: instead of `replace` use `match` with same regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
$logFileTree = $logFile -replace '[^\\]*$'
```

it will replace everything that is not a `\` at the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

Use Split-Path.

```
Split-Path $logFile
```

If you need the trailing '\' (I wouldn't recommend it), append it.

```
(Split-Path $logFile)+'\'
```